# Adding HTML Doctype, centers <td> children in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This is happening only in IE. I have tested it in IE7, IE8, and IE9.

If I remove the html doctype, then the td tags are left justified. But if I add any of the standard HTML4 or 5 tags, it centers the text and inputs.

It works fine in other browsers. I can easily fix this by `td { text-align: left; }`, but I kind of want to know why this is happening.

Any of the following doctypes causes this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

I'm surprised I couldn't find an answer to this, but I googled and searched here and found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is going into what is called "Quirks mode" when there is no doctype specified.

the idea is that it should make the interpreter more compatible. but in fact quirks mode just makes most stuff not work properly. so always declare a doctype in IE.

the thing with the default td centered is just another IE incompatibility of html standards, nothing special.
i couldn't find out about it or test it though, IE11 dev tools dont allow quirks, and IE7 and IE8 mode makes the td's left aligned for me. maybe there is another rule in your code that make the IE behave strangely.

Comment: `maybe there is another rule in your code that make ie behave strange.` yeah, that's what I was thinking. I didn't develop this, but from going through all the computed styles and rendered HTML, I couldn't find anything.

Comment: just declare a doctype and explicitly define the css rules that behave differently. thats what developers have done for what seems ages to solve the "Internet Explorer Issue"